# Is it possible to bind to a property on the container of the Adorned Element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF app we are using an adorner for displaying validation messages, in the particular case there is a single row grid that has multiple controls some of which have validation. The problem I'm having is that I want to force the width of the error message control to be the same as the grid but can't seem to find a way to reference that grid from the adorner template. Here is a sample of what I tried:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Local_TopAdornedTemplateWide">
    <StackPanel>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adornedElement"/>
        <TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, ElementName=adornedElement}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Local_ValidationErrorMessageConverter}}" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource Error_Text}" 
                   Padding="2 1 0 0" 
                   Visibility="{Binding ElementName=adornedElement, Mode=OneWay, Path=AdornedElement.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                   />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This causes the application to crash with an XamlParseException.

Ideally the solution would not be specific to a grid so that it would get the width of any container type, but for now grid is the only use case.

**Edit:**
Here is an example of another template we use in the application; this template would not work for my case as it would limit the error to be the width of a single column of the aforementioned grid:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="Local_TopAdornedErrorTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adornedElement"/>
            <TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=adornedElement, Path=ActualWidth}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Local_ValidationErrorMessageConverter}}" 
                       Style="{DynamicResource Error_Text}" 
                       Padding="2 1 0 0" 
                       Visibility="{Binding ElementName=adornedElement, Mode=OneWay, Path=AdornedElement.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                       />
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Using snoop I captured the following two screenshots (I could not take one of the full stack to prevent posting anything proprietary)

This shot shows the grid I mentioned previously, within this it is the FinancialTextBox item that is being adorned

[image: Adorned item]

This shot shows two things, the item selected in blue is the highest ancestor of the grid in the previous shot, the yellow highlight is the Textbox from the content template

[image: Adorner]

With those two it seems to be apparent that (based on information from Contango's answer) the two items aren't not in the same visual tree which would lead me to believe my question is not possible. However the second template I added (which does work) points that at least some visual information from the adorned element lives on in the place holder.

So now my question boils down to a) does this information include the parent of the adorned element and b) how can this be accessed via a binding on a different element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ended up being a lot simpler than the path I was trying to go down.

I was doing some reading on the AdornedElementPlaceholder class and came across [this entry on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.adornedelementplaceholder(v=vs.110).aspx) and noticed that the class actually has a property called parent, with that I tried the following binding and it works perfectly:

```
MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=adornedElement, 
                   Mode=OneWay, 
                   Path=AdornedElement.Parent.ActualWidth}"
```

Answer (score -1):

WPF is quite powerful and flexible.

You can bind any property in any XAML tag to any property in any other XAML tag.

For example, you could write a test app that binds the `Text` property of an input box to the `Text` property of a label, so as you type something into the text box, the label would change automatically (assuming you use  `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`). This is a direct XAML to XAML binding, with no C# in sight.

Similarly, you could bind the width of your error box to the width of the parent control, whatever that may be.

Google `RelativeSource` and `AncestorType`, this is a great link:

http://druss.co/2013/10/wpf-binding-examples/

See if you can grok how the Visual Tree and Logical Tree works in WPF, once you understand that, you will understand more of how binding works.

I'd also recommend using the free tool `Snoop` to look at the Visual Tree. `XAML Spy` is excellent, but not free.

`Snoop` can tell you if there is anything that has a bad binding at runtime (you set the filters up, and it will list all bad bindings).

You can use `Snoop` to get the full XAML path of your source (the XAML you wrote above), then get the full XAML path of the target (i.e. the `ActualWidth` of your `Grid`), then compare them: it may be quickly apparent that one is not the ancestor of the other, as they are on different branches of the visual tree, or that there is some other issue which is preventing a simple walk up the visual tree from working.

If you just want to get something working, as a proof of concept, try naming the target XAML grid using `x:Name`, and reference it by name instead of `AncestorType`.

Comment: Although this is some great information, I don't really see how it addresses my problem specifically; and perhaps it is just because my question is not clear enough.  Naming the grid is not really an option as the template is a shared resource that can be used anywhere in the application so it needs to be more generic. I have used snoop to investigate the object graph and the Textblock in question does not fall within the scope of the grid, not directly at least. I will add a some screenshots to demonstrate this.

Comment: Just added info on how to use Snoop to disgnose the issue.

Comment: Also to be clear, though no expert, I am generally pretty comfortable using  RelativeSource and AncestorType. My blocker here is trying to get an ancestor of a sibling, rather than a direct ancestor as is the norm.

Comment: @Phaeze I understand. Could you try walking the tree up to the ancestor, then walk down into the appropriate sibling?

Comment: again I cannot do that because I cannot know how many levels up or back down to traverse, this template needs to be able to work no matter where it is used in the visual tree. And I have been able to answer one of the clarified questions in the edit; it looks like the adornedElementPlaceholder does not provide access to the ancestors of the adorned element.

Comment: So with that question answered I have something I'm going to try later today, going to try switching the stackpanel out for a panel that does not provide infinite width, it should implicitly give me what I'm looking for.